# Populating MySql db with ftp server CSV data

Tags: mysql, ftp

is there a way to extract csv's data present in a FTP server to MySql Db present on a Server?
My vendor dumps the data in csv files on the ftp server. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In with technology or language do you want to perform this action. There are many possibilities to do above task from ftp server to mysql or Linux server or windows server etc.

Comment: I tried with PHP scripts but failed each time. I would still like to get this done using PHP, however JAVA is an another option!

Comment: If you want i will help you to retrieve data from ftp using Java and load that data in you db.

Comment: Please! it would be very helpful! But i must tell you I am only a beginner in java :(

Comment: Dn't wry @Joe I will help you will full code of Java that will get file from FTP server to your local server and load that data to your db

Comment: There are some question regarding this. 1- How many files are there on FTP? 2- Does each file has same column in data? 3- Do you have username, password and file path of FTP server to read files?

Comment: 1). The sender of the csv file is dumping files once in every 10 minutes with change in name. so they just keep stacking up. 2) Yes! 3) FTP credentials are with me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can FTP to mysql? No.

But you could fire a cron job on the FTP server (or another server that can retrieve files from the FTP server) and then process them in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution, using a bash shell script, add it to crontab to have this run automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCAL_CSV_PATH="/path/to/local/csv/destination/"
CSV_FILE_NAME="file.csv"

#
# Lets Get This File - delete this section if your csv is local to yoru
#
FTP_HOST='127.0.0.1'
FTP_USER='user@example.com'
FTP_PASS='pass'
FTP_FILE="/path/to/$CSV_FILE_NAME"

# Call 1. Uses the ftp command with the -inv switches.  
#     -i turns off interactive prompting. 
#     -n Restrains FTP from attempting the auto-login feature. 
#     -v enables verbose and progress.  

ftp -inv $FTP_HOST << EOF
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
cd $LOCAL_CSV_PATH
mget $FTP_FILE
delete $FTP_FILE
bye
EOF


#
# Import this file
#

MYSQL_USERNAME=user
MYSQL_PASS=pass

# IFS is the internal field seperator used by bash, set to "," for csv files
IFS=,
while read column1 column2 column3
      do
        echo "INSERT INTO my_table (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('$column1', '$column2', '$column3');"
      done < "$LOCAL_CSV_PATH/$CSV_FILE_NAME" | mysql -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p $MYSQL_PASS my_database;

# Cleanup
mv "$LOCAL_CSV_PATH/$CSV_FILE_NAME" "$LOCAL_CSV_PATH/$CSV_FILE_NAME.old_run"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below Java code to read file from FTP server and store all file data into Database from each file reside in FTP directory path.

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class ftpRead {

    public static String sDir = "";
    public static FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    public static int replyCode;
    public static boolean success = false;
    public static String server = "ftp server ip";
    //int port = ;
    public static String user = "ftp username";
    public static String pass = "ftp password";

    public static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) throws IOException {

        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
                //return "false";
            }

            success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                // return "false";
            } else {
                System.out.println("User successfully logged in.");
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("ftp_file_directory");//directory Changed

                FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();//get list of files and folders

                for (int ii = 0; ii < files.length; ii++) {

                    InputStream fstream = null;
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    DataInputStream in = null;

                    if (files[ii].isDirectory()) {//check for file or directory


                        System.out.println("Directory name  " + files[ii].getName());//print directory name

                    } else {

                        System.out.println("file name  " + files[ii].getName());//print file name
                        //  try {
                        ftpClient.connect(server);
                        showServerReply(ftpClient);
                        replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
                        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                            System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
                            //return "false";
                        }
                        success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);

                        showServerReply(ftpClient);
                        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("path_ to_file_directory");
                        fstream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(files[ii].getName());

                        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String strLine = null;
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String dataline = strLine;
                        String insertBackup = "insert into tablename values(" + dataline + ")";
                        exeQuery(insertBackup);


                        if (strLine.trim().length() == 0) {
                            continue;  // Skip blank lines
                        }

                    }

                    }
                }


            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
        }

    }

    public static void exeQuery(String query) {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "mysqluser";
        String password = "mysqlpass";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + "database_name", userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            Statement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Download all support library from following links.

[FTP Library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsnet301jar.htm)

[MySQL connector](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector.jar.zip)

**Note**: Please make sure you have mad changes in this code according to your FTP credentials , Database credentials etc.

Comment: Got the following Error:                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at ftpRead.main(ftpRead.java:88)

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Yeah the code works fine for logging in into the FTP server. But can't make out what that error is indicating?

Comment: Make sure your ftp directory path is currect? `ftp_file_directory`

Comment: I have given the ftp directory path correctly. But what should I mention in static String sDir=""; ?

Comment: Is there a reason to reconnect/login before you retrieve each file?